# Is it worth to advertise a fundraiser?

Tags: profitability, non-profit

I have several crowdfunding fundraisers, mainly nonprofit projects (however personal, without official NGO registration).

Is it expected to be worth to buy PPC Internet ads to advertise one of my fundraisers? If yes, about what profit margin can I expect?

Note: it seems on-topic to ask this question accordingly comments at [Is asking for a general investment strategy profitability on-topic?](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2670/6685)

Comment: Forget on/off topic for a moment. How can members possibly provide a useful answer? I answer "My fundraising efforts for abandoned puppies with big puppy dog eyes has used PPC very successfully" and another replies "Our PPC effort to save the manatee was a waste of money".  PPC has been around a long time, and is as successful as each user reports. Results vary widely, of course.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like the many instances in investment where knowing the outcome before plonking down the dough would be extremely profitable.

Unfortunately, when the proof of the pudding is in the eating, there’s no way around plonking down the dough first.